# Do remote images in FPDF get physically inserted into the PDF file?

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

I'm looking to generate a PDF document on the fly using FDPF, via a PHP script. Looking at the [documentation for the Image function](http://fpdf.org/en/doc/image.htm), it appears I can indeed use remote images. However, can some one tell me, is the image physically inserted into the PDF or pulled from the remote server each time the PDF is viewed, i.e. if the user were to save the document?

I'm just thinking what would happen if the remote image changed, or was no longer available. My guess is that the image is physically inserted into the document, but would like to know for certain. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the image is embedded in the actual PDF file. You can verify that by checking the file size of the actual document.